# Datepicker takes default date when change it in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I have 2 date pickers, start-date and end-date. I set date picker with default of current date.

```
var currentDate = new Date();
    $(".datepicker").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);
```

But I try to change the dates, it will not work, following is my code to change

```
$('body').delegate('select.project','change',function(){
        var val=$('.project :selected').val(); 
        $.post('ajax/project.php',{ajax:'projdt',did:val},function(data){
            var val=data.split('-');
            sdt=val['0'];
            $(".sdt").datepicker("setDate",sdt);
                $('input.sdt').prop('disabled', true);

            edt=val['1'];
            $(".edt").datepicker("setDate",edt);
                $('input.edt').prop('disabled', true);

            alert(sdt);alert(edt);
        });
    });
```

html :

```
<select class="project" name="project" data-rel="chosen">
<option value="1">app</option>
<option value="2">website</option>
<option value="3">blog</option>
</select>

<input type="text" class="datepicker sdt" name="sdt" value="">
<input type="text" class="datepicker edt" name="edt" value="">
```

Comment: you need to provide your markup as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('body').delegate('select.project','change',function(){
        var val=$('.project :selected').val(); 
        $.post('ajax/project.php',{ajax:'projdt',did:val},function(data){
            var val=data.split('-');
            sdt=val['0'];
            edt=val['1'];

            $(".sdt,.edt").datepicker('option', {minDate:sdt,maxDate:edt});
            $(".sdt").datepicker('setDate',sdt);
            $(".edt").datepicker('setDate',edt);

        });
    });
```